# Issue in identifying objects in salesforce application functional flows

Tags: community, salesforce1-app, sandbox, salesforce-id, test-automation

Currently I am doing a POC on salesforce automation using Serenity BDD framework with Selenium Webdriver.

While automating ,the objects inside a iFrame is not working to complete end-end flow.

I am performing for a end-end flow for Lead Creation.For this I am using Serenity BDD framework Where I am trying to access the iFrame in POM.

**Page1**:

I have a Select Lead Record type page where i need to select a record Type(personal banking,business banking etc.,) from a dropdown and continue button
The iFrame log depiction is below for same

**Div id**:

```
<div id="ext-comp-1022" class=" x-border-panel x-border-layout-ct" 
style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 345px; height: 729px;"><iframe id="ext-
comp-1023" name="ext-comp-1023" frameborder="0"/>
```

===>Note:This is the div tag above iFrame tag as below

**iFrame id:**

```
<iframe id="ext-comp-1023" name="ext-comp-1023" frameborder="0" src="Url " class=" x-border-panel" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 345px; height: 729px;"></iframe>
```

===>Note:This is the  iFrame where there are two objects –

a)dropdown

b)continue which are not working on executing script.its says there is no frame by id or name.object property details of the record type select is given below which is under this iFrame

```
#<<=select id="p3" name="p3">>#

#<<option value="01228000000CzgZ">>BusinessBanking<</option>>#

#<<=/select>>#
```

Similarly the Continue button is not working.

Code depiction of how I m accessing the objects in POM.java file
For SelectLeadDropdown

```
public void SelectRecordType(){

      waitABit(30000);

      getDriver().switchTo().frame("ext-comp-1023");//tried various possibilities for iFrame and as well as various other waits etc.,


      waitFor(SlctRecordType);

selectFromDropdown(SlctRecordType,"Business Banking");


   }
```

**Page2**

I have another Page – New Lead page, where I need to fill details of Lead(i.e., probable customer in layman terms) which is also objects inside a iFrame . I have below object in the page. I am facing the same issue as Select Lead Record page .i.e., page 1

•   LeadLastName-  textbox

•   LeadCompany – textbox

•   LeadStatus – dropdown

•   LeadSource – dropdown

•   Save - button

Also tried various other possibilities for making objects to work in POM but still the issue persists

a)Tried to use the dropdown as textbox

b)Tried accessing div frame id (ref  Div id section above), iFrame id (ref  iFrame id section above) etc as captured from html pageSource

c)Included wait for application sync and wait for the element using WaitFor before accessing the object inside the frame.

d)Tried using various locators possibilities for objects in POM.

Also noticed that the Frame id for the Select Lead Record Type conflicts with the New lead pages.Both pages shows iFrame as same when spied.

Observation regarding the iFrame id -

Also noticed the iFrame id keeps changing frequently (it is not static)
Few of the instances where the iFrame id values changed are

•   Observed that the iFrameid differs when spying the values in two different chrome in different machines

•   When more than one instance of application is opened in same or different machine

•   When login to a new session, the id sometime dynamically changes.

Other issue is when automating objects which are not in frame, that too fails – e.g, after login any objects in the header –username display check also fails
Kindly look and advice me on the same and highly appreciated.Feel free to reach me on the same..

Thanks & Warm Regards,

Barath

9884592899

Barath.star81@gmail.com

Comment: Adding more information to the posted question : application is salesforce sandbox

Comment: Re-adding the log information

Comment: Re-adding the log information                                                                                                       **Div id**:
<div id="ext-comp-1022" class=" x-border-panel x-border-layout-ct" >===>Note:This is the div tag above iFrame tag as below

**iFrame id:**
<iframe id="ext-comp-1023" name="ext-comp-1023" .."></iframe> 
object property details of the record type select is given below which is under this iFrame

#<<=select id="p3" name="p3">>#
#<<option value="xx">>BusinessBanking<</option>>#
#<<=/select>>#

Comment: Adding more info to question : Most objects are inside the salesforce console

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand - you have a page (page1) which has a Picklist/dropdown and a 'Continue' button. When you hit 'Continue', an iframe pops up, which also has a Picklist/dropdown and a 'Continue' button which aren't working as expected. Please do correct me if I'm wrong.

The page that you are populating in the iframe, which has the second set of dropdown and 'Continue' button, is that a page you have control over, or is it a standard/external page that you are trying to embed?

Comment: Hi James,                                                                                                                      The page 1 i.e., the Select lead record type page,which as two objects - Dropdown and a continue button,both are in frame.The objects are inside frame and not accessible.As I  click Continue button in Page 1 manually i end in page 2 - i.e, "New Lead page" which has objects in ques abv          . These objects are also in frame.I am unable to access it as I have mentioned before.I tried switching to frames etc but it is not successful. I am using serenity BDD framework.